# Escaping ? (question mark) in hibernate/gorm sql restriction

Tags: sql, postgresql, grails-orm

I'm attempting to query against a materialized path stored with postgres ltree type from a Grails application. Unfortunately, my query uses the "?" operator which is being captured by GORM as a parameter

```
sqlRestriction("materialized_path ? (SELECT ARRAY(SELECT CAST(CAST(subpath(?,0,generate_series) AS text) ||'.*{1}' AS lquery) FROM generate_series(1,nlevel(CAST(? AS lquery)))))"
                ,[vertex.materializedPath,vertex.materializedPath])
```

Where that first question mark should be escaped and the error being thrown is

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No value specified for parameter 4.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.checkAllParametersSet(SimpleParameterList.java:246)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:272)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:430)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:356)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:168)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:116)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it myself with a little experimentation. It just takes a double-question mark. So,

```
"materialized_path ? (SELECT ARRAY(...
```

becomes

```
"materialized_path ?? (SELECT ARRAY(
```